# iOS Slide out menu, need it to be accessible on every View Controller

Tags: ios

As title suggests, how would you go about doing that?
Basically, I need a slide out  menu to be accessible from every screen.

Currently, I have a navigation stack, that you have to dismissViewController each view controller (back button) on the stack, in which then you can launch the menu. I need the menu to be launched from any screen.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [project](http://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController)

It should solve your problem.
I applied it in the root view and I can slide from anywhere.

Comment: Is it possible to show a relevant snippet of code? Link-only answers often go obsolete, and are hard to search for.

Comment: I found my issue. I was presenting new view controllers with [self pushViewcontroller:vc]; , when I should have been using [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

Comment: using project linked by Anurag works (not sure why I got downvoted?)